# Track App open events using Fabric's Answers

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

My app is using Fabric's Answers for events tracking, and I'm about to launch a Twitter Campaign (on ads.twitter.com), which integrates with Answers, but I'm getting this error saying that App open are not being tracked. I went to Answer's control pannel and couldn't find anything related to App open event tracking. There are a bunch of other events, and custom event, but no app open (that Twitter would recognize). Is there a way to track app open using Fabric's Answer?

[image: Image showing the warning because of the lack of app open tracking]

Thank you very much!!